# Unable go get the github private module. Issue with "go get" Command: Invalid Version Error

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang, I attempted to use the go get command to download a package from a GitHub repository (github.com/********). However, I encountered an error that I'm struggling to resolve.

**Here's the error message I received:
**
go: downloading *********
go: github.com/********: verifying module: github.com/********: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/!**: 404 Not Found
server response:not found: github.com/********: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/aa19b2d6105a267dbfc8bf55238c68423f1cefd2710ee05e45e772bc91d03ad1: exit status 128:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.

Title: Issue with "go get" Command in Golang: Invalid Version Error

Description:
I'm new to Golang and I've been trying to set up my environment. As part of this, I attempted to use the go get command to download a package from a GitHub repository (github.com/********). However, I encountered an error that I'm struggling to resolve.

Here's the error message I received:

go: downloading *********
go: github.com/********: verifying module: github.com/********: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/!**: 404 Not Found
server response:not found: github.com/********: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/aa19b2d6105a267dbfc8bf55238c68423f1cefd2710ee05e45e772bc91d03ad1: exit status 128:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.

I've already created a .netrc file in C:/users/ directory with my GitHub username and token, but it seems like Git is not able to read it or authenticate properly.

As I'm new to Golang, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue further. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!